# generalize R function for variable input

Tags: r

I wish to generalize a `function` so it can contain a variable number of inputs.  Here is an operational version of a `function` when there are three `cACL` variables and three `rACL` variables.  I would like the function to be able to handle an `n.obs` number of `cACL` and `rACL` variables.  The user would create the input data set `master.iter` with the desired number of `cACL` and `rACL` variables and ideally the `function` would handle the rest.  The `function` would need to be generalized in three places: the `my.function` input statement, the equation for `xx` and the `apply` statement.

I have seen several similar questions here, but none seem to apply here or were not reproducible.  I need this in base `R`.  The equation shown here for `xx` is irrelevant.

```
master.iter <- read.table(text = '
   scenario  aa   bb  cACL1  cACL2  cACL3  rACL1  rACL2  rACL3
          1   2   80     10     20     30      1      2      3
          2   4   60     11     21     31      4      5      6
          3   6   40     12     22     32      7      8      9
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

n.obs <- length(grep('cACL',  colnames(master.iter), value=TRUE))
n.obs
#[1] 3

my.function <- function(scenario, aa, bb, cACL1, cACL2, cACL3, rACL1, rACL2, rACL3) {

     xx <- aa * bb + (cACL1 + cACL2 + cACL3) - (rACL1 + rACL2 + rACL3)

}

my.function.output <- apply(master.iter, 1, function(x) {
     my.function(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8], x[9])})
my.function.output
#[1] 214 288 282

# check function results
2 * 80 + (10 + 20 + 30) - (1 + 2 + 3)
4 * 60 + (11 + 21 + 31) - (4 + 5 + 6)
6 * 40 + (12 + 22 + 32) - (7 + 8 + 9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need change your function like this:

```
my.function <- function(scenario, aa, bb, cACL, rACL) {
     xx <- aa * bb + sum(cACL,na.rm=TRUE) - sum(rACL,na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Where cACL and rACL are `numeric` objects.

Comment: This function statement seems to work in `apply` with your approach: `function(x) {my.function(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4:(3+n.obs)], x[(3+n.obs+1):(3+n.obs*2)])}`

Answer (score 1):

An option is to reshape to 'long' format and summarise

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(master.iter, cols = cACL1:rACL3, 
  names_to = c('.value', 'grp'), names_sep="(?<=^.)(?=.)") %>% 
  group_by(scenario) %>%
  summarise(out = (first(aa) * first(bb)) + sum(c) - sum(r))
```

---

Or another option is to use `split.default` in `base R`

```
Sum1 <- sapply(split.default(master.iter[4:ncol(master.iter)],
    substr(names(master.iter)[4:ncol(master.iter)], 1, 1)), rowSums)
with(master.iter, (aa *bb) + Sum1[,1]  - Sum1[,2])
#[1] 214 288 282
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I really need this in base R.  The actual program is huge and very complex.

Comment: @MarkMiller I added a base R option as well

Comment: I will see if I can insert this into the structure of the function I provided and activate it with the apply statement I provided.

Comment: @MarkMiller your function have a lot of arguments.  Instead you can specify the argument for 'aa', 'bb' and the column index from `4:ncol`

Answer (score 0):

In Base R, if the way you name your data is maintained, then you could do:

```
df <-reshape(master.iter, 4:ncol(master.iter), dir = "long", sep="")

df1 <- aggregate(.~scenario+aa+bb, df, sum) 

with(df1, data.frame(scenario,result = aa * bb + cACL - rACL))

  scenario result
1        3    282
2        2    288
3        1    214
```

If at all you must use `apply`: which I strongly object, then you could write a function like below and use it as follows:

```
my.function <- function(x, vars){
  x <- setNames(as.list(x), vars)
  
  my_fun <- function(aa, bb, ...){
    x <- list(...)
    aa * bb -diff(c(rowsum(unlist(x), substr(names(x), 1, 1))))
  }
  
  do.call(my_fun, x)
  
}    
apply(master.iter[-1], 1, my.function, names(master.iter)[-1])
[1] 214 288 282
```